# React build on electron appimage not showing static images

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron

I have the next structure on my project:

[Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aO2NS.png)

It is a project created with create-react-app, and the build folder is the build of the project. I builded an app image with electron builder. When i open the image it works perfectly but didn't load any image from assets. What am i doing wrong?

[That is my package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pt546.png)

i don't know what to do please help me.

Comment: Did you managed to solve it?